# iPhone is not discoverable over bluetooth low energy

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am using CoreBluetooth Framework. I created the demo app to discover the bluetooth low energy devices. As iPhone 4s and above devices supports Bluetooth Low Energy, Am not able to discover another iOS devices over Bluetooth Low Energy from my demo app.

My iPhone has iOS7 running.

Here is my code. I am trying to discover another iPhone from my iOS app. I created Central Demo App. Do I need to create another demo app for peripheral and deploy it on another iPhone, which i wand to discover?.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];


}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    // You should test all scenarios
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // Scan for devices
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        NSLog(@"Scanning started");
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

}
```

Comment: No code, no answer. Please include source code of your demo application.

Comment: Yes, you need to have a BLE peripheral to discover.  An iOS device does not advertise BLE services by default - you need to write an app to advertise a service and characteristics.  You can use an app such as LightBlue to advertise a peripheral

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741 This link helps you to understand.. make one device as peripheral and one as receiver... It works AND to understand how it works: check this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-theoretical-overview--mobile-20728

Comment: Can you confirm that BLE devices are never discoverable in the iOs Settings app ? (With the exception of ANCS solicitation)